# Pixelwise scrolling for LO/OO Writer

Tags: openoffice-writer, libreoffice-writer

In LO/OO Writer vertical scrolling can be done e.g. by moving the text cursor up/down, using the mouse wheel, clicking the up/down arrows on the vertical scrolling bar, etc.

Touch scrolling (on touch screens) is not supported, unfortunately. Therefore I wrote a tool (in Autohotkey) which enables touch scrolling. It is working fine, but the scrolling is not as smooth as in other programs supporting touch scrolling: the content of the window is moved in steps of approx. one line.

In my tool I am using the best 'control' for scrolling I could find: touch point movements are remapped to clicks on the up/down arrows on the vertical scrolling bar.

MY QUESTION: Is there (could there be) another 'control' in LO/OO Writer which would allow smoother (pixelwise) scrolling of the displayed content?

Thank you very much in advance for your answers! (Please only answers referring to LO/OO Writer.)

Comment: Clicking and dragging the scrollbar allows higher granularity than the up/down arrows.

Comment: @Jim K: You mean the scrollbar thumb? Hm ... Click and drag on the thumb can be made pixelwise, but the content of the window doesn't follow this movement smootly.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking and dragging the scrollbar allows higher granularity than the up/down arrows.  The scroll amount adjusts if the document is zoomed in.

On the downside, using the scrollbar is much more difficult than a simple click on the arrows.  There is a discussion at https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/51041-click-drag-scrollbars/.

If it is a touch screen, perhaps you could require the user to touch the scrollbar, so the touch location would give the vertical position of the scrollbar.  Then use [MouseClickDrag](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClickDrag.htm) starting from that position.

Comment: Already testet: Click and drag on the thumb can be made pixelwise, but the content of the window doesn't follow this movement smootly!!! (And the discussion refers to Firefox, which is not comparable to LO/OO Writer ...)